# glMapBuffer is missing from opengl es 2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Why `glMapBuffer` is missing from opengl es 2.0? Who we can get access to buffer data to change it efficiently? Only `glBufferSubData` is the best way to modify the buffer?

Comment: What platform are you working on? Try finding an extension to get that functionality such as "#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>".

Comment: @MaticOblak I don't find it in OpenGL ES 2.0 documentations as well. You think it is no missing?

Comment: I think it should be there but I am not 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glMapBuffer` is an [extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_mapbuffer.txt) in ES 2.0, not part of the core spec. The vast majority of devices (all iOS and most Andriod) offer the extension, but it is not required. The only core way to upload VBO data is with `glBufferData`, or `glBufferSubData`.

Comment: But it is native to OpenGL 2.0?

Comment: it was introduced in OpenGL 1.5, so yes, it is core in GL 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

You need extension [GL_OES_mapbuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_mapbuffer.txt). This provides glMapBufferOES and glUnmapBufferOES.

There is a separate extension for mapping subranges: [GL_EXT_map_buffer_range](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_map_buffer_range.txt).

Comment: glMapBufferRange is also useful for more than just mapping subranges -- it has new usage flags so you don't have to manually hint the driver to orphan the previous buffer with glMapBuffer(NULL)

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way to transfer your buffer depends on the data access patterns and the OpenGL driver you are targeting.  Here is a great article on choosing between the many options even on OpenGL ES 2.0:

http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2013/04/there-must-be-50-ways-to-draw-your.html

Here is a newer article about the similar techniques.  It seems that persistent mapping is the state-of-the-art as of OpenGL 4.5:

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming

Lastly, the book "Open GL Insights" has an entire chapter on this issue which is included in the free preview:

http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf